# Nginx always reports "not found"

Tags: nginx

Trying to get an nginx setup running but every time I visit the address, I'm given "not found" instead of the laravel site I'm expecting.

Server worked fine before I added the vhost, so I'm guessing there is something misconfigured there. Any help spotting the error would be appreciated.

Please note, site can only be accessed by IP which is why I have the filler IP `123.123.123.123` for `server_name`.

etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
listen 80;

user  nginx;

worker_processes 4;

worker_rlimit_nofile 200000;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 4000;

    use epoll;

    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include  /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

etc/nginx/site-available/mysite.conf:

```
server {
    server_name  123.123.123.123;
    access_log  /srv/www/mysite/logs/access.log;
    error_log  /srv/www/mysite/logs/error.log;
    root  /srv/www/mysite/public_html/public;
    rewrite_log  on;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main buffer=16k;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    #gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js;

    open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;

    sendfile on;

    tcp_nopush on;

    tcp_nodelay on;

    keepalive_timeout 90;

    keepalive_requests 100000;

    reset_timedout_connection on;

    client_body_timeout 30;

    send_timeout 30;

    # Remove trailing slash to please Laravel routing system.
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite  ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files  $uri =404 $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        include  /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        #fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/mysite/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # We don't need .ht files with nginx.
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    # Set header expirations.
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|jpe?g|JPG|png|svg|woff)$ {
        expires  365d;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in the error log?

Comment: `/srv/www/mysite/logs/error.log` is empty and so is `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: Finally produced an error but I don't know what it means: `[error] 29745#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 321.321.321.321, server: 123.123.123.123, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "123.123.123.123"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include from **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/** so make sure when you add a new config to **/etc/nginx/site-available/** that it is available from the latter, e.g.

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.conf
```

In your mysite.conf also add a **listen** directive like

```
server {
    listen 123.123.123.123;
    server_name  123.123.123.123 "";
    ...
}
```

The **""** is for empty HOST header requests, just to be fine with that.

**Update** further tests:

Define an access-default.log for the main server and an access-mysite.log so that you can see who says "not found" (not just error-logs).

Also use wget to access every server (your IP-Server and the proxied server) and look in the logs.

Add a "root" directive to the main server's location and try to access a non-proxied file (like index.html) to see who thinks is responsible.

You can, during your tests, also mark the virtual server as default_server for all requests ([see the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)).

Comment: This didn't fix the problem. Still getting "not found" when I visit the IP. I also did a symlink on the dir `sites-available` instead of by file....but that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: Symlinking the whole directory is not necessary. If you add an error on purpose you will immediately see if your file is included or not on nginx-reload :) - updated my answer.

Comment: I changed `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/mysite/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;` to `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` and that fixed the problem, but your response helped me find it. Thanks! Now I have a new "not found" problem. The main IP loads but every Laravel route is given the "not found" treatment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your mysite.conf add a listen directive :

> ```
> server {
> listen 80 default;
> server_name  123.123.123.123 "";
> ...
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Added it, but this didn't fix the problem. Still getting "file not found".